# How can I insert information to my MYSQL database from PHP for my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, web

I am trying to create a new account on my website by using the INSERT INTO mySQL method, in my PHP file. For some reason, the database is not receiving the information I am sending to it. My question is: how can I create a new account with php? The first part of my php code is just validating the text submitted from the html page.

This is my php code which I am using to verify and send data to my database hosted through 000webhost.com.

```
 <?php

$host=""; // Host name (all these are correctly filled in in my code)
$username=""; // username
$password=""; // password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$mypassword1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$mypassword2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);
$myemail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$myfirst=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
$mylast=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']); 

if(!($mypassword2 == $mypassword1)){
  $message = "passwords do not match!";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
 }
 else{

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' or email='$myemail'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);  


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $myusername;

if($count > 0){
  $message = "Username or Email already in use!";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `first`, `last`, `email`, `grade`,             `skype`, `phone`, `credentials`) 
VALUES (NULL, \'$myusername\', \'$mypassword1\', \'$myfirst\', \'$mylast\', \'$myemail\', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);';

$message = "inserted!";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}  

}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form name="create_account" method ="post" action="php/new_account.php">
                <fieldset class="account-info">
                    <label> First <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First"> </label>
                    <label> Last <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last"> </label>
                    <label> Email <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">         </label>
                <label> Username <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"> </label>
                <label> Password <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" placeholder="Password"> </label>
                <label> Confirm Password <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;"> </label>
                <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="account-action">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                <a href="login.html" id="log"> Login </a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Database image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiwur.png

Comment: That question title is horrible. And the `mysql_` functions are deprecated; use PDO or `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not running a query at all. This is only a string:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `first`, `last`, `email`, `grade`,             `skype`, `phone`, `credentials`) 
VALUES (NULL, \'$myusername\', \'$mypassword1\', \'$myfirst\', \'$mylast\', \'$myemail\', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);';
```

You need to run it with

```
mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Also you should put your connection in a variable:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
```

---

You are using a deprecated library. mysql_ is deprecated and you are highly vulnerable to sql injection. You should change your connection to [**mysqli_**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!